# Infinitesimal Generator of Ito Diffusion Process

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-analysis, semigroup-of-operators

Suppose one has the an Ito process of the form:

$$dX_t = b(X_t)dt + \sigma(X_t)dW_t$$

The following is an excerpt from wikipedia

[image]

My question is on how to derive this operator? It looks very similar to what you get when using Ito's Lemma. So I start with applying Ito's Lemma with f to get:

$$df = \frac{\partial f}{\partial t}dt + \sum_i\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}dx_i + \frac{1}{2}\sum_{i,j}\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_ix_j}[dx_i,dx_j]$$

Which then becomes:

$$df = \left[ \frac{\partial f}{\partial t}dt + \sum_i b_i(X_t)\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}dt + \frac{1}{2}\sum_{i,j}(\sigma\sigma^T)_{i,j}\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_i \partial x_j} \right]dt + \sum_i \sigma_i(X_t) \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}dW_t$$

Hopefully I got that correct. What I'm unsure about is how to proceed in order to compute $Af(x)$. I would think the next step is to integrate $df$, but it's not clear to me what happens after (I know these infinitesimal generators are rooted in semigroup theory, but I have very little experience in that).

Comment: Brenton, what do you mean by $\sigma_i$? Wasn't it $\sigma(X_t)$ a matrix valued function?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**Hints:**

1. Note that $f$ does not depend on the time $t$, therefore the term $\frac{\partial}{\partial t} f$ is superfluous.
2. Take expectation on both sides, then the stochastic integral $\dots dW_t$ vanishes, because it is a martingale.
3. Use Fubini's theorem and the fundamental theorem of calculus, $$\frac{1}{t} \int_0^t \mathbb{E}^xg(X_s) \, ds \stackrel{t \to 0}{\to} \mathbb{E}^xg(X_0)= g(x).$$

Comment: Thanks for the help! Doing steps 1 and 2 gives me this: $E[f] = E\left[ \int_0^t \left[ \sum_i b_i(X_t)\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}dt + \frac{1}{2}\sum_{i,j}(\sigma\sigma^T)_{i,j}\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_i \partial x_j} \right] ds \right]$. I'm not sure I'm understanding how to use Step 3 though.

Comment: @Brenton ... because you didn't write up Itô's formula properly. You can use these short-notations if you know what you do, but at the beginning it's much better to write it in full length. by Itô's formula $$f(X_t)-f(X_0) = \int_0^t \dots \, dW_s + \int_0^t \dots \, ds.$$ Fill in the "$\dots$" and take then the expectation on both sides. Then you'll see that e.g. the left-hand side in your comments reads $\mathbb{E}^x f(X_t)-\mathbb{E}^x f(X_0)$.

Comment: So if I do it this way (to my understanding since I've never taken an SDE course):

$$f(X_t) = f(X_0) + \int_0^t  \sum_i \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}b_i  + \frac{1}{2}\sum_{i,j}\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_ix_j}(\sigma \sigma^T)_{ij} ds  + \int_0^t \sum_i \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}\sigma_i dW_s$$

So taking expectations should give:

$$E^x \left[f(X_t)\right] = E^x \left[f(X_0)\right] + E\left[\int_0^t  \sum_i \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}b_i  + \frac{1}{2}\sum_{i,j}\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x_ix_j}(\sigma \sigma^T)_{ij} ds\right]$$

I feel like I made a mistake

Comment: @Brenton Actually, it should read $$f(X_t) = f(X_0) + \int_0^t \left( \sum_i \frac{\partial f(X_s)}{\partial x_i}b_i(X_s) + \frac{1}{2}\sum_{i,j}\frac{\partial^2 f(X_s)}{\partial x_ix_j}(\sigma(X_s) \sigma(X_s)^T)_{ij} \right) ds  + \int_0^t \sum_i \frac{\partial f(X_s)}{\partial x_i}\sigma_i(X_s) dW_s.$$

Comment: Ok that looks essentially what I have. So taking expectations should give the following:

$$E^x[f(X_t)] = f(X_0) + E\left[ \int_0^t  A(X_s) ds \right]$$ where $A(X_s)$ is everything in the $ds$ integral above.

By Fubini, I should have: $$E^x[f(X_t)] = f(X_0) + \int_0^t  E\left[A(X_s)\right] ds $$.

Is that correct?

Comment: @Brenton Yeah; however, I recommend you to write $f(x)$ instead of $f(X_0)$ (as long as you keep in mind that $X_0 = x$ $\mathbb{P}^x$-almost surely, there is nothing wrong about the equation in your previous comment, but you have to be more careful if you want to play around with $x$.)

Comment: Ah ok. I was not aware that $f(X_0) = f(x)$ a.s. That might've been part of my confusion. So I should have that:

$$LV(x) = \lim_{t \rightarrow 0} \frac{1}{t} \int_0^t E[A(X_s)] ds$$

My last question is why as $t \rightarrow 0$ does the expression tend to $E[A(X_0)] = A(x)$. I feel like this is an elementary calculus fact (I found it here: http://www.mecca.org/~halfacre/math/lesson29.htm but I don't really understand their reasoning for the last step in the proof, and it's been about 8 years since I took calculus). I appreciate the help a lot

Comment: @Brenton By the fundamental theorem of calculus, $$\frac{1}{t} \int_0^t g(s) \, ds \to g(0)$$ as $t \to 0$ for any function $g$ which is continuous at  $0$. Use this for $g(s) := \mathbb{E}^x[Af(X_s))$. (Don't forget the $x$; it really makes a difference whether you write $\mathbb{E}$ or $\mathbb{E}^x$.)

Comment: Ah ok yes I see why now (mainly needed a calculus review haha). So when they write $f(x)$, it can be thought of as $f(X_0)$ where $X_0 = x$ a.s.?

Comment: @Brenton $X_0 = x$ $\mathbb{P}^x$-almost surely implies $f(x) = f(X_0)$ $\mathbb{P}^x$-almost surely; yes.

Comment: Thank you very much. I've seen $LV(x)$ used in some papers sometimes to make calculations easier. I'm curious why else the infinitesimal generator is important, like what else it tells you about an SDE. I know for Brownian Motion, the infinitesimal generator is used to solve the heat equation, but I'd imagine it has more uses

Comment: @Brenton You might have a look at this question: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/694227/ My answer concentrates on Brownian motion, but actually all these things can used/extended for a much larger classes of proceses (including SDEs).

Comment: Thank you for this. You've really helped me a lot. I'm going to go accept your answer.

Comment: Hmm, it's still not totally clear.  You said one can apply the fundamental theorem of calculus if $g$ is continuous at $0$, but then you didn't argue why $g(s) = \Bbb E^{x}[Af(X_{s})]$ is continuous at $0$.  Why is this $g$ continuous at $0$?

Comment: @user46944 Note that $(X_t)_{t \geq 0}$ has continuous sample paths and $y \mapsto Af(y)$ is continuous (for any "nice" $f$). Therefore the continuity of $s \mapsto \mathbb{E}^x (Af(X_s))$ is a direct consequence of the dominated convergence theorem.

Comment: @saz How do you know that $\mathbb E\left[\int_0^t \sigma (X_s) f'(X_s) d W_s\right]$ is a martingale? This is not the case in general. https://almostsuremath.com/2010/08/16/failure-of-the-martingale-property/

Comment: @MatheusManzatto By assumption, $f$ (and hence also its derivative $f'$) are compactly supported. This means that square integrability of the integrand is satisfied if, say, $\sigma$ is continuous (because then $\sigma$ is bounded on compact sets). Square integrability then entails that it is a "real" martingale.

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation!!

Comment: Dear @saz what is $\sigma_i$? Isn't $\sigma(X_t)$ a matrix valued function?

Comment: @MAB it should denote the $i$th row of the matrix $\sigma$, so that $\sigma_i(X_s) dW_s$ is the $i$th component of the stochastic part of $dX_s$.