# Change of generators with an additional drift

Tags: reference-request, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-analysis

Let $Z_t$ be a Levy process with the generator $A$, and consider the following SDE:
$$
dX_t=f(X_t)dt+dZ_t,
$$
may I know can I represent the generator $L$ of $X$ in terms of $A$?

[This](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-319-02684-8_1) gives if $f(X_t)=BX_t$, the generator of $X$ is given by
$$
Lu=Au+Bx\cdot \nabla u.
$$
Then can I conjecture that 
$$
Lu=Au+f(x)\cdot \nabla u,
$$
for more general $f$? Could you provide some ideas about how to approach the problem or some references on this topic?

Comment: Yes, that's correct - at least for functions $u$ which are sufficiently regular. For instance if $u$ is twice differentiable, you can prove the assertion by applying Itô's formula.

Comment: @saz Do you mean I can establish the desired result for Lipschitz $f$ by mimicking the process of identifying the generator of Ito-diffusions?

Comment: Yes, the main difference is that you need Itô's formula for jump processes (and not only for Itô diffusions).

Comment: @saz Thank you. However, I was wondering where I consider $\frac{E^x[f(X_t)]-f(x)}{t}$ as $t\to 0$, do I need to consider the usual [pointwise convergence](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1347558/infinitesimal-generator-of-ito-diffusion-process?rq=1) or the [uniform convergence](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/694227/what-is-the-importance-of-the-infinitesimal-generator-of-brownian-motion)?

Comment: You can either a) show uniform convergence or b) show pointwise convergence and that the limit function $Lu$ is continuous and vanishes at infinity.