# Is $I(\omega_0) = J(\omega_0)$ for this homogeneous continuous-time Markov chain?

Tags: stochastic-processes, random-variables, markov-chains, markov-process

Assume $(X_t)_{t\ge 0}$ is a homogeneous continuous-time Markov chain on the probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{G}, \mathbb{P})$. Moreover, $X_1(\omega_0) = X_2(\omega_0)$ for some $\omega_0 \in \Omega$. Consider two random variables:

- $I = \inf \left\{t \geq 1 \mid X_t \neq X_1\right\}$
- $J = \inf \left\{t \geq 2 \mid X_t \neq X_2\right\}$

I would like to ask if we can conclude $I(\omega_0) = J(\omega_0)$. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: As random variables? Definitely not. Nor are they necessarily the same for this particular $\omega_0$. Nor do they even necessarily have the same distribution, unless you also assume that $X_3$ is the same (because effectively you have a kind of "Brownian bridge" between time $1$ and $2$ that you don't have after time $2$).

Comment: @Ian If I modify $I,J$ into $I = \inf \left\{t \geq 1 \mid X_t \neq i\right\}$ and $J = \inf \left\{t \geq 2 \mid X_t \neq i\right\}$. Can we obtain any improvement?

Comment: These are just the same thing, as long as $X_1(\omega_0)=i$.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer @Ian! I will post your comment as answer to close this question.

Comment: @Ian Recently, I have asked some questions about continuous-time Markov chain, but none of them receives any attention. Because I'm doing my thesis, I hope that you can have a look at them. They are [1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3649606/how-to-recover-the-continuous-markov-chain-from-its-infinitesimal-generator), [2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3648887/given-the-infinitesimal-generator-how-a-continuous-markov-chain-behaves-after-t), and [3](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3644829/how-is-holding-time-h-i-defined-in-continuous-time-markov-chain).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I convert @lan's comment as answer to close this question.

---

> As random variables? Definitely not. Nor are they necessarily the same for this particular $\omega_0$. Nor do they even necessarily have the same distribution, unless you also assume that $X_3$ is the same (because effectively you have a kind of "Brownian bridge" between time $1$ and $2$ that you don't have after time $2$).