# Taylor's formula - infinitesimal generator

Tags: limits, stochastic-processes, taylor-expansion, stochastic-calculus, limits-without-lhopital

As it is written [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/694227/what-is-the-importance-of-the-infinitesimal-generator-of-brownian-motion), using the Taylor's expansion, one can write

$$
\mathbb{E}^xf(X_t) \approx f(x)+t Af(x)
$$
from 
$$
Af(x) := \lim_{t \downarrow 0} \frac{\mathbb{E}^x(f(X_t))-f(x)}{t} 
$$
where $A$ is the infinitesimal generator and $\mathbb{E}^x$ is the expected value.

Can anybody explain how the first approximation was achieved? It is just simply a cross multiplication in the limits?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$Af(x) = \lim_{t \downarrow 0} \frac{\mathbb{E}^x(f(X_t))-f(x)}{t}$$
implies that 
$$\lim_{t \downarrow 0} \mathbb{E}^x(f(X_t))-f(x) - tAf(x) = \lim_{t \downarrow 0} t \left[ \frac{\mathbb{E}^x(f(X_t))-f(x)}{t} - Af(x) \right] = 0$$
which tells you that
$\mathbb{E}^x(f(X_t)) \approx f(x) + tAf(x)$ for small $t \geq 0$.

Comment: How $\lim_{t \downarrow 0} \mathbb{E}^x(f(X_t))-f(x) - tAf(x)$ was derived from the definition? multiplied both sides by t? And why could it be assumed that the term in the big bracket is zero?

Comment: We want to look at $\lim_{t \downarrow 0} \mathbb{E}^x(f(X_t))-f(x) - tAf(x)$ because we want to see that $\mathbb{E}^x[f(X_t)] \approx f(x) + t Af(x)$; it isn't derived from the definition of $A$. The definition of $A$ is used to see that the limit as $t \to 0$ of the term in the big brackets is $0$ (the term in the brackets itself isn't $0$, it's important there's a limit there)

Comment: Thank you for the fast response. How did you conclude $\mathbb{E}^x(f(X_t)) \approx f(x) + tAf(x)$ from $\lim_{t \downarrow 0} \mathbb{E}^x(f(X_t))-f(x) - tAf(x) = 0$

Comment: This isn’t a precise statement since $\approx$ isn’t precisely defined. The heuristic statement being made is just the meaning of the limit though

Comment: so why $\lim_{t \downarrow 0} \mathbb{E}^x(f(X_t)) \approx \mathbb{E}^x(f(X_t))$?

Comment: What you’ve written doesn’t make sense? On the left hand side you send $t$ to 0 but on the right it’s fixed (and unspecified)

Comment: I think i confused every thing. I dont understand why $\lim_{t \downarrow 0} \mathbb{E}^x(f(X_t))-f(x) - tAf(x) = \lim_{t \downarrow 0} t \left[ \frac{\mathbb{E}^x(f(X_t))-f(x)}{t} - Af(x) \right] = 0$ tells us that $\mathbb{E}^x(f(X_t)) \approx f(x) + tAf(x)$

Comment: The statement I made is that **for small t** $\mathbb{E}^x(f(X_t)) \approx f(x) + tAf(x)$ where you should notice that the symbol $\approx$ has no precise meaning (though I will say what I mean by it in this comment for clarity). The limiting statement then means that for any 'amount of error' $\varepsilon$ there is a $\delta$ such that $0<t< \delta$ ('for small t') $|\mathbb{E}^x(f(X_t))-f(x) - tAf(x)| < \varepsilon$ (which is what should be understood as $\mathbb{E}^x(f(X_t))\approx f(x) + tAf(x)$).