# Time derivative of the mapping $t \mapsto P_tf(x)=\mathbb{E}^x(f(X_t))$ - infinitesimal generator

Tags: stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, laplacian

Can anybody please explain equation $1$ in this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/697412/767953) in a simpler form? Also i cannot understand how from equation $1$ we can see that $u$ is the solution to the heat equation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**

\begin{align}
\frac{\mathrm d }{\mathrm dt}P_tf(x)&=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{P_{t+h}f(x)-P_tf(x)}{h}\\
&=\lim_{h\to 0}P_t\left(\frac{P_hf(x)-f(x)}{h}\right)\\
&=P_t\left(\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{P_hf(x)-f(x)}{h}\right)\\
&=P_tAf(x)\\
&=AP_tf(x).
\end{align}
I let you justify each equality as a homework. For your other question, one can prove that the infinitesimal generator of the Brownian motion if given by $$Af(x)=\frac{1}{2}\Delta f(x).$$
Do it as a homework if this is not clear for you.

Comment: Thanks. Putting the solution to  $\partial_t u(t,x) = \frac{1}{2}\partial_x^2 u(t,x) \qquad u(0,x)=f(x)$  gives an extra term $\frac{1}{2} \partial_x^2 (\frac{t}{2}f''(x))$ May i ask why this last term vanishes?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand your question. I don't see where your extra term comes from. @Denis

Comment: actually,  i am  checking if $\mathbb{E}^x(f(B_t)) \approx f(x)+ \frac{t}{2} f''(x)$ is the solution to the heat equation. But it does not satisfy the heat equation, and we have the mentioned extra term...

Comment: As you remarked, $\mathbb E^x[f(B_t)]\approx f(x)+\frac{t}{2}f''(x),$ but they are not equal. They even don't have the same regularity... and obviously, $f(x)+\frac{t}{2}f''(x)$ doesn't satisfy heat equation @Denis

Comment: But in the linked post, it is argued that : 
"From (1) we see that $u(t,x) := \mathbb{E}^x(f(B_t))$ is the (unique) solution of the heat equation.."
and he already defined $\mathbb E^x[f(B_t)]\approx f(x)+\frac{t}{2}f''(x)$

Comment: Honnestly, I don't see any connection between the fact that $\mathbb E^x[f(X_t)]$ solve the heat equation, and the fact that $f(x)+\frac{t}{2}f''(x)$ should solve it... obviously, It won't solve the heat equation, since a priori $x\mapsto f(x)+\frac{t}{2}f''(x)$ is not derivable. @Denis

Comment: Sorry, i am really confused here. So, why in the linked answer, the person did the effort to obtain the approximation? and more importantly, if that is not the correct way, what is the correct way? any hint is really appreciated...

Comment: @Denis: Look, take the Cauchy problem $y'(x)=y(x)$, $y(0)=1$. The (unique) solution is given by $y(x)=e^x$. You have that $y(x)\approx 1+x$ (if $x\ll 1$), but $x\mapsto 1+x$ is not a solution of $y'(x)=y(x)$.

Comment: @Denis: For a Hint, you have that $$p(x,t)=\mathbb E^x[f(X_t)]=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi t}}\int_{\mathbb R}f(y)e^{-\frac{(y-x)^2}{2t}}\,\mathrm d y.$$ Thus you can easily compute $\partial _tp$ and $\partial _{xx}p(x,t)$.

Comment: Thanks, just a last short question :
Do you know why in the linked answer, the person tried to obtain $\mathbb E^x[f(B_t)]\approx f(x)+\frac{t}{2}f''(x)$? What did he want to show with obtaining this?

Comment: @Denis: $\mathbb E^x[f(X_t)]$ can be very diffcult to compute. Nevertheless, when $t$ is small, it should be close to $f(x)+\frac{t}{2}f''(x).$